# Find the limit of $U_n$ that satisfies $x_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{3n+11}(\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt[3]{7+x_n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, fractions

Find the limit of $U_n$ that satisfies \begin{cases}
x_1=\sqrt[2022] \frac{2022}{2021}\\
x_{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{3n+11}(\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt[3]{7+x_n}), \forall n \in \mathbb{N*} \end{cases}

I am always confused when I comes to a sequence with no fixed pattern, that is the coefficient ( like $\frac{n+2}{3n+11}$) is changed.

One thing I can assume is that for $n \to +\infty$, then $\frac{n+2}{3n+11} \to 1/3$, then assume $L$ is the existed limit, we can solve for $L=1$.

Now what I tried to do is that I subtract both sides in someway so that $x_{n+1}-1$ or $x_n-1$ in someway, but apparently that yield no results ( and doesn't even work as well).

Should I change my approach? What tools should I use?

Comment: Experimentally, it seems to converge monotonically to 1 from below, starting with $x_2$.

Comment: Try to prove something like the following.  If $x_n \ge 1$, then $x_{n+1}<x_n$. If $x_n<1$, then either $x_{n+1}> 1-\frac1n$ or $x_{n+1}>x_n$. The terms might have to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if the sequence converges, $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n.$ We see that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+2}{3n+11} \left(\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt[3]{7+x_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt[3]{7+x_n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n.$$ Thus, in the limit, we have that $$\frac{1}{3}\left(\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt[3]{7+x_n}\right)=x_n.$$ Solving gives $x_n=1,$ so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=1.$$